# mongoDb find fieldname regex

Tags: mongodb

Here is my document :

```
> db.a.find({})
{  "a" : 1, "b" : { "23" : "c", "24" : "d" } }
{  "a" : 2, "b" : { "25" : "e", "26" : "c" } }
```

If i find with

```
> db.a.find({'b.23':'c'})
```

i get the document

But in my case i don't know the key before hand and i want to find all keys if it has value 'c' :

```
> db.a.find({'b.*':'c'})
```

THIS DOESN'T WORK !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty horrible solution because I hate posting things that essentially require the use of the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) JavaScript execution but:

```js
db.docs.find(function(){
    for ( var k in this.b ) {
        if ( this.b[k] == "c" )
            return true;
    }
})
```

Would actually see that both documents contain some key that matches the value you are looking for.

The direct use of `function()` here is an "implicit" usage of the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator. I really don't like it for reasons specified in the documentation, but if it is what you need then it is what you need.